# What is the Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerance?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, distributed, fault

Can somebody please provide a gist of the  Byzantine Fault Tolerant algorithm and Liskov's algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that what the good people at wikipedia have already done. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault_tolerance

Comment: No. The Page doesn't contain the algorithm itself.

Answer (score 3):

I think the introduction to Chapter 4 of Castro and Liskov's article from 1999 gives a concise and good overview of the inner workings of the algorithm: http://pmg.csail.mit.edu/papers/osdi99.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can know much details of how PBFT works by reading [the paper](http://pmg.csail.mit.edu/papers/osdi99.pdf) published in OSDI(1999).

If you want to have understanding the *algorithm* throughly used in PBFT, then, I highly recommend [doctoral thesis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.65.2508&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and [technical paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5a13/aec02c85e739e5242b0a9da287e7281fee97.pdf). Both are written by original author, Miguel Castro. It contains almost everything that you want to know about PBFT. And if you want to see its implementation in code-level, you can download and check the software in [this page](http://www.pmg.csail.mit.edu/bft/).